# How this code line is reading power consumption information?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, sysfs

I came across following program that reads power consumed by ARM based raspberry pi and writes it to another file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    // Open the power consumption file
    std::ifstream powerFile;
    powerFile.open("/sys/devices/platform/soc/c440000.qcom,spmi/spmi-0/spmi0-02/c440000.qcom,spmi:qcom,pm8150b@2:qpnp,fg/power_supply/bms/power_now");

    if (!powerFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open the power file." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the log file
    std::ofstream logFile;
    logFile.open("power_log.txt", std::ios::app); // Append mode

    if (!logFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open the log file." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Get the current time
    auto currentTime = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

    // Read power consumption data
    std::string powerData;
    std::getline(powerFile, powerData);

    if (!powerData.empty()) {
        double powerConsumed = std::stod(powerData) / 1000000.0; // Convert to milliwatts

        // Log the data to the file
        logFile << "Time: " << std::ctime(&currentTime) << "Power Consumed: " << powerConsumed << " mW" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read power data from the file." << std::endl;
    }

    // Close the files
    powerFile.close();
    logFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I dont know if its correct or not. How I am puzzled by following line:

```
powerFile.open("/sys/devices/platform/soc/c440000.qcom,spmi/spmi-0/spmi0-02/c440000.qcom,spmi:qcom,pm8150b@2:qpnp,fg/power_supply/bms/power_now");
```

It does not seem to be name of the file and it seems like some comma separated value or something.  What does this line do?

Comment: Why did you tag this C?  It's C++ code.

Comment: This is more a Linux question than a programming question. As far as C++ is concerned, you're just opening a file.

Comment: /sys is a virtual file system so my guess is that the suff after , is configuration to whatever driver generates the file.  Find the source.

Comment: more of a linux question than a programming one, see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysfs.5.html

Comment: Related: [What populates the /sys and /dev directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/715801/564341)

Comment: Try `cat "/sys/devices/platform/soc/c440000.qcom,spmi/spmi-0/spmi0-02/c440000.qcom,spmi:qcom,pm8150b@2:qpnp,fg/power_supply/bms/power_now"`

Comment: "It does not seem to be name of the file" Why do you think that? All those punctuation characters are allowed in filenames.

Comment: Presumably something write power consumption stats into that virtual file. The given code simply reads the file. The magic I think you are looking for is elsewhere.

Comment: Try reading the file using `cat` as above, then calculating pi to 10000 digits in another window and checking the file again. Try `bc -l <<< "scale=10000;4*a(1)"`

Comment: Indeed ... just because you don't know Linux doesn't make this a programming question. Much better suited for [unix.se] or [su]

Answer (score 2):

`/sys` is mounted to a certain virtual filesystem (virtual ``disk'').
So the file that you name is a virtual file - when you read from it, the kernel does some actions and generates the data. The particular virtual filesystem mounted to `/sys` is [sysfs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysfs.5.html).

What data are generated can be found in the sources of linux kernel or perhaps in the sources of some kernel module (parts of the `/sys` are changed dynamically).

The actions to obtain the data depend on the particular device; it may go down to some 2-wire physical communication, for example. Some places where I see `pm8150` (or `qcom` or `spmi`) are: [mfd](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mfd/), [dtsi](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm64/boot/dts/qcom/pm8150b.dtsi?h=v6.5-rc6), [read](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/spmi/spmi.c?h=v6.5-rc6), [spmi](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/spmi/spmi.yaml?h=v6.5-rc6), [qcom](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/soc/qcom?h=v6.5-rc6); [qcom,pm8150b](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mfd/qcom%2Cspmi-pmic.txt) in [mfd](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mfd/).

It comes to my mind that since the communication can be slow, the information could be cached. But it is equally possible that your `read` operation could block your program for some time.

Possibly some of the directories are actually symbolic links, so you may get some more information by looking at the output of `ls -l sys/devices/platform/soc/c440000.qcom,spmi/spmi-0/spmi0-02/` or longer or shorter paths.